# Does the Keywarden in Act 4 randomly drop keys?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was hunting for the infernal machine plans in act 4, and instead of dropping the plans the keywarden dropped the key of hate. I was on monster level 2 I, don't think that matters, just wondering if the final keywarden can drop keys randomly to save time when hunting for keys in the future?

Comment: This is covered under the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

According to diablo 3 wiki, Since the patch 1.08, the last Keywarden [Nekarat](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nekarat_the_Keywarden) can also drop one of the key randomly : [Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Keywarden)

Comment: Side note, it can drop both the plan and a key.